# Как установить библиотеку в Java?

Tags: java

Я не совсем понимаю как это делать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если под добавлением библиотеки вы подразумеваете добавление какого-нибудь jar-файла к проекту, то есть разные способы.

Если вы компилируете и запускаете проект из консоли, то нужно прописать путь до интересующего jar-файла в *classpath*.
Так может выглядеть запуск класса `Main`, находящегося в пакете `org.example.somepackage`, с добавлением jar-файла library.jar, находящегося в папке `D:\folder1\folder2`.

```
java -classpath D:\folder1\folder2\library.jar org.example.somepackage.Main
```

Разумеется, что classpath должен содержать не только путь до добавляемого к проекту jar-файла, но и путь до вершины иерархии пакетов проекта, но это уже другая история. Вот неплохая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/125210/) на тему работы с Java из консоли.

Можно использовать среду разработки. Вот пример для IntellijIdea:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings (Libraries) -> + -> Java -> выбираете путь к jar-файлу -> OK -> apply.
```

Можно использовать сборщик. Вот пример для Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

При этом надо понимать, что с точки зрения подключения jar-файлов ни среда разработки, ни сборщик не делают ничего удивительного. Они точно так же, как вы можете сделать вручную, прописывают в classpath путь до добавляемого jar-файла. Ну, разве что сборщик самостоятельно скачивает jar-файл на ваш компьютер.